# Function runs in Iron Python (Python(x,y) Spyder2 IDE) but not in Python 2.7 Console

Tags: python, python-2.7, sqlite, pyqt4, ironpython

I am using the Spyder2 IDE in the python(x,y) package. The below function runs fine in Iron Python, but has errors when I run in the console. I need it to run in the console so that I can use Pyinstaller. The error I get is: `"Error binding parameter 0. Probably unsupported type."` The line showing the error is the "cur.execute" line. I'm also using Sqlite3 and getting text data from PYQT4 lineEdit fields.

Here is the code:

```
def update_clients(self):
    #Get client id from list
    cid = None
    try:
        cid = self.client_list_id()
    except:            
        QtGui.QMessageBox.warning(self, 'Warning', 'You must first select a client before you update')


    if cid:
        #Get update items
        first = self.lineEdit_c_first.text()        
        last = self.lineEdit_c_last.text()
        add1 = self.lineEdit_c_address1.text()
        add2 = self.lineEdit_c_address2.text()
        city = self.lineEdit_c_city.text()
        state = self.lineEdit_c_state.text()
        zipp = self.lineEdit_c_zip.text()        
        phone = self.lineEdit_c_phone.text()
        cell = self.lineEdit_c_phone_cell.text()
        off = self.lineEdit_c_phone_office.text()
        email = self.lineEdit_c_email.text()  
        notes = self.textEdit_c_notes.toPlainText() 
        #Update database
        conn = sqlite3.connect('gibbs.db')
        cur = conn.cursor()
        sql = ("""
        UPDATE clients
        SET 
        firstname = ?, 
        lastname = ?,
        address1 = ?,
        address2 = ?,
        city = ?,
        state = ?,
        zip = ?,
        phone = ?,
        officephone = ?,
        cell = ?,
        email = ?,
        notes = ?        
        WHERE rowid = ?
        """)
        cur.execute(sql, (first, last, add1, add2, city, state, zipp, phone, off, cell, email, notes, cid,))
        conn.commit()
        conn.close()

        QtGui.QMessageBox.information(self, 'Success', 'Database successfully updated')
```

Additionally, since the issue is somehow related to data types, here is the code that I used to create the database tables:

```
import sqlite3

def create_connection():

    try:
        conn = sqlite3.connect('gibbs.db')
        return conn
    except:
        pass 
    return None

def create_clients():
    try:
        conn = create_connection()
        print conn
        c = conn.cursor()
        c.execute("""
        CREATE TABLE clients (
        id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
        timestamp DATETIME DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
        firstname TEXT,
        lastname TEXT,
        address1 TEXT,
        address2 TEXT,
        city TEXT,
        state TEXT,
        zip TEXT,
        phone TEXT,
        officephone TEXT,
        cell TEXT,
        email TEXT,
        notes TEXT    
        )     
        """)
        conn.close()
    except:
        print "table already exists"
```

Comment: What do you get from `print first` prior to trying to insert?

Comment: Spyder maintains state between runs; that is some assigned values remain, and helper functions that you may have deleted are still alive. Does your function still run on a fresh kernel (restart spyder)?

Comment: @roganjosh I printed the sql variable and that worked fine.

Comment: @ReblochonMasque The function runs fine on a fresh kernal also.

Comment: @ReblochonMasque  No. Sorry. The function ran fine on a fresh "Iron Python" console. Still throwing the error on Python2.7 console

Comment: @roganjosh The printed output of 'print first' prints the contents of the PYQT4 lineEdit correctly. In this case it prints "Bob" without the quotes.

Comment: Scratching my head on this one mate sorry. What is `print(type(first))`?

Comment: @roganjosh your head scratching is much appreciated. Also, you may be on to something. 'print type(first) in Iron Python outputs: <type 'unicode'> and in Python2.7 console it is: <class 'PyQt4.QtCore.QString'>.

Comment: Hmm, I wonder why that is? What happens if you use `str(first)` in the query? Does the error then shift to binding parameter `1`? I'm wondering if you can cast to string directly, in which case I guess you could `map` `str` on to the values you're trying to insert.

Comment: @roganjosh I think that might work. When I did str(first) the type output was <'str'> in both versions and the IP version still works. Now I'm getting error on binding parameter "1" instead of "0" on console. I think it's solved. I'll let you know in a few. Thanks!

Comment: @roganjosh That solved it. Thank you for your help.

Comment: No problem. I don't know Iron Python so I'm oblivious as to why this was an issue but at least I know there might be a pitfall with things that look like string objects in Spyder :)

Comment: I suggest you write this up as an answer btw. My comment about not knowing Iron Python is to say that I don't know why it implicitly converted this data to strings for you (which actually helped you out previously). Then you can close the question by accepting your own answer (which is perfectly fine to do). If someone in future can explain why this difference exists, you can swap accepted answers (which might happen before you get chance to accept your own answer anyway since there's a time threshold on that)

Comment: @roganjosh  Will do although you probably had more to do with the solution than me.

Comment: Then mention in your answer that I helped :) I don't care beyond that nod, it was interesting to solve.

Answer (score 1):

I added the line `print type(first)`, as suggested by @roganjosh, just before the query. When running the program, the result was different in the two consoles. The Iron Python console outputs: `<type 'unicode'>` and in Python 2.7 console it is: `<class 'PyQt4.QtCore.QString'>`.

I solved by adding the `str()` function when getting my text from the PYQT4 lineEdits. For example:

```
first = str(self.lineEdit_c_first.text())
```